# In what sense is Bell's inequality "probabilistic", while the GHZ experiment is "definite"?

Tags: quantum-information, bells-inequality

I read the paper about the GHZ contradiction written by David Mermin and he said that Bell's inequality is probabilistic while GHZ experiment is definite.

Here is that paper:https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.65.1838

I hear that the difference between Bell's inequaltiy and GHZ expeirment is the definiteness.

What's the meaning of the definiteness here and why Bell's inequality is called probabilistic?

Could you please explain it mathematically?

Comment: related on QCSE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9536/55

Answer (score 7):

In Bell the *probability* of certain events is different in classical and quantum mechanics so one needs to make many measurements to verify that the Bell inequality is violated. In  GHZ the application of classical logic together with an assumption of the existence of  "reality" leads to the prediction that the product of a certain set of three measurements is always $+1$. Quantum theory (and experiment) says the same product is always $-1$. No probability is involved in GHZ.

The math: Consider a system consisting of *three* space-like separated  (and therefore causally isolated)  isolated spin-$\frac 12$ particles.
The
three-particle Hilbert space is eight-dimensional, and  a state in this space is a linear combination of states such as
$$
|{\uparrow,\downarrow,\uparrow}\rangle\equiv |{\uparrow}\rangle\otimes
|{\downarrow}\rangle \otimes|{\uparrow}\rangle.
$$

Let  ${\rm A}^{(1)}=\pm 1$  denote  the result of measuring the  $x$ component of  spin ''1,''
and ${\rm B}^{(1)}=\pm1$  the result if we elect instead to  measure its $y$ component.
Suppose that we separately  measure ${\rm  A}^{(1)}$ , ${\rm B}^{(2)}$, and ${\rm B}^{(3)}$ and
multiply the results to get the number  ${\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm B}^{(2)}\, {\rm B}^{(3)}=\pm 1$.
This observable corresponds to the operator
$
\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_y\otimes \sigma_y.
$ Similarly
$$
{\rm  B}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm B}^{(3)} \mapsto \sigma_y\otimes\sigma_x\otimes \sigma_y,\nonumber\\
{\rm  B}^{(1)}\, {\rm B}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)} \mapsto \sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y\otimes \sigma_x.\nonumber
$$

The three operators $\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_y\otimes \sigma_y$,
$ \sigma_y\otimes\sigma_x\otimes \sigma_y$ and $\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y\otimes \sigma_x$ commute with each other, and can therefore be
simultaneously diagonalized.

The state
$$
|{\Psi}\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt
2}(|{\uparrow,\uparrow,\uparrow}\rangle-|{\downarrow,\downarrow,\downarrow}\rangle)
$$
is a simultaneously  eigenvector of the  three operators above  and in each case the
eigenvalue is  +1.

Thus, when we prepare the system in the state $|\Psi\rangle$ and elect to measure any of these three sets of observables,  the individual  A's and B's may  vary, but their  product will always be $+1$.

The measurement
$$
{\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)}\mapsto \sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x\otimes \sigma_x\
$$
always returns  $-1$ when the system is in state   $|{\Psi}\rangle$.

Now for the philosophical conundrum: If the quantities being measured existed independently of the measurement
process, we would be able to predict  the value of the product
${\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)}$ from the measured values  of
${\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm B}^{(2)}\, {\rm B}^{(3)}$,
${\rm  B}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm B}^{(3)}$ and
${\rm  B}^{(1)}\, {\rm B}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)}$. This is because
$$
({\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm B}^{(2)}\, {\rm B}^{(3)})
\, 
({\rm  B}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm B}^{(3)})
\, 
({\rm  B}^{(1)}\, {\rm B}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)})
\equiv 
({\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)})
$$
each B having been measured twice, and $B=\pm 1$ means that $B^2=1$.

Using this logic, together with   the measurements from above  we deduce that should always find that $({\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm
A}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)})=+1$. However the quantum calculation  it clear that an actual  measurement
will always give  {$({\rm  A}^{(1)}\, {\rm A}^{(2)}\, {\rm A}^{(3)})
=-1$.

Comment: Could you please explain it mathematically if possible? I heard this a lot but it is a bit uncertain for me.

Comment: I've added the math for GHZ.